# Como passar informações de um produto com parametros e puxar no carrinho de compras?

Tags: php, ajax, array, session, array-multidimensional

eu sou novo na área de programação e estou criando um ecommerce, até que eu me deparei com a seguinte situação ao enviar meu formulário via ajax.

Os itens vendidos no site possuem parâmetros, como por exemplo:

O usuário pode comprar o projeto 01, porém dentro do projeto 01, ele pode escolher entre alguns ítens, como um projeto eletrico, um projeto estrutural, dentre outros projetos pertencentes ainda ao projeto 01.

Eu estou criando uma sessão para armazenar os parâmetros de cada projeto selecionado.

Porém não estou sabendo como poderia fazer para armazenar os dados de um projeto dentro de um array que automaticamente vai armazenando os itens escolhidos de seu respectivo projeto.

Este é minha requisição para onde envio mu ajax para criar minhsa sessão.

```
<?php
    include('../config.php');
    //Declaração de sessões
    if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['codigo']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['valor'])) {

        $conteudo = [$_POST['nome'],(int)$_POST['codigo'],(int)$_POST['id'],$_POST['valor']];
        $idProjeto = (int)$_POST['id'];

        if (isset($_SESSION['pack']) == false) {
            $_SESSION['pack'] = [];
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['pack'][$idProjeto]) == false) {
            $_SESSION['pack'][$idProjeto];
            $_SESSION['pack'][$idProjeto][1] = $conteudo;
        }else{
            $_SESSION['pack'][$idProjeto][] = $conteudo;
        }

        echo json_encode($_SESSION['pack']);
    }
?>
```

No meu carrinho de compras eu estou resgatando minha sessão desta forma.

```
    <ol>
    <!-- Aqui são os nome dos itens que foram selecionados no projeto pelo usuário -->
        <?php
            $retornoProjeto = $_SESSION['pack'];
            foreach ($retornoProjeto as $key2 => $retornoProjeto[]) {
                foreach ($retornoProjeto[$key2] as $key3 => $retorno2) {
                    if ($retornoProjeto[$key2][$key3][1] === $$_SESSION['carrinho']) {
        ?>      
        <li><?php echo $retornoProjeto[$key2][$key3][0]; ?></li>
        <hr>
        <?php 
            }
                }
                    } 
        ?>
        <ol>
        <!-- Aqui é o valor dos itens que foram selecionados no projeto pelo usuário -->
        <?php
            $retornoProjeto = $_SESSION['pack'];
            foreach ($retornoProjeto as $key2 => $retornoProjeto[]) {
                foreach ($retornoProjeto[$key2] as $key3 => $retorno2) {
                    if ($retornoProjeto[$key2][$key3][1] === $_SESSION['carrinho']) {
        ?>          
        <li>R$ <?php echo $retornoProjeto[$key2][$key3][3]; ?></li>
        <hr>
        <?php 
        }
            }
                } 
        ?>
        
        </ol>
```

Cada Projeto vendido possui 7 itens opcionais.
Se puderem me ajudar por favor ficaria muito grato!!!
Eu realmente travei nessa parte, primeiro site hehe
Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o meu problema, este é o meu codigo para onde envio minha requisição.

```
<?php 
include('../config.php');
//Declaração de sessões
if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['codigo']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['valor'])) {

    $codigoProjeto = (int)$_POST['codigo'];
    $idItem = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $conteudo = [$_POST['nome'],(int)$_POST['codigo'],(int)$_POST['id'],$_POST['valor']];

    if (isset($_SESSION['pack']) == false) {
        // Eu NÃO tenho a $_SESSION['pack'] -> Preciso criar minhssa SESSION e dizer que ela tem um array;
        $_SESSION['pack'] = [];
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto])) {
        // Eu NÃO tenho a $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto] -> Preciso passar o valor do meu $_SESSION['pack'][?] e dizer que o valor do array é o codigo do meu projeto e que dentro do código do meu projeto eu preciso criar outro array vazio e passar o identificador do item selecionado;
        $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto] = [];
        if (!isset($_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem])) {
            // Eu NÃo tenho a $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] -> Preciso passar o valor do id do checkbox;
            $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = [];
            $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = $conteudo;
        }else{
            // Eu tenho a $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] -> Preciso passar os valores dos meus parâmetros referente ao id do checkbox, e rodar um loop de incremento no id do item do checkbox;
            $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = $conteudo;
        }
    }else{
        // Eu tenho a $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto];
        if (!isset($_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem])) {
            $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = [];
            $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = $conteudo;
        }else{
            $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = $conteudo;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($_SESSION['pack']);
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma olhada no seu código, e tenho uma sugestão de melhoria, baseado no php sniffer, code smeel e clean code. Com isso fica mais fácil de entender e com menos linhas. Dica: procure estudar sobre esses 3 assuntos, irá te ajudar muito.

```
<?php
include('../config.php');

// Inicia a session
session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['nome'])){
    return "name is required";
}
if(!isset($_POST['codigo'])){
    return "code is required";
}
if(!isset($_POST['id'])){
    return "id is required";
}
if(!isset($_POST['valor'])){
    return "value is required";
}

$codigoProjeto = (int)$_POST['codigo'];
$idItem = (int)$_POST['id'];
$conteudo = [
    $_POST['nome'],
    (int)$_POST['codigo'],
    (int)$_POST['id'],
    $_POST['valor']
];

/* Eu NÃO tenho a $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] 
   -> Preciso criar minha SESSION e 
   inserir o conteúdo de $conteudo que é um array */

if (!isset($_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem])) {
    $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] = $conteudo;
}

/*Eu tenho a $_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem]; 
    e vou inserir mais um conteúdo nela */
$_SESSION['pack'][$codigoProjeto][$idItem] []= $conteudo;

echo json_encode($_SESSION['pack']);
```